# Prevent one link in a list from taking on e.preventDefault();

Tags: jquery

I have this Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mainNav a").bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        nav = $('.header').height() - 10;

        var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-nav
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

which is all good as it targets all my link generated from wordpress menu, but the problem is i don't want e.preventDefault(); on the /blog link as this needs to link to another page and not link down the page, i need this to be in my JQuery as i cant add specific class itd all generated via WP, so basically if its a # link prevent default or vis versa

```
<div class="mainNav">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#work">Our Work</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#something">Something</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/blog/">Blog</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: j08691's answer will work given your menu always only has these 3 things on it.  But you can also customize the behavior of `wp_nav_menu()` and how it adds classes via PHP by writing a custom walker function (so you could for instance add the page link's title as a class).  See here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function

Comment: ill look into thois one thank you, was looking for a quick JQuery fix, but this is something ill investigate

Comment: Your best bet is to use the native jQuery selectors. There are other solutions which involve checking the clicked element's `href` attribute, but this is inefficient because the function is being called for all anchor tags, not just the ones you want. Instead, limit binding your event listeners to only the local anchor tags by using `$(".mainNav a[href^='#']")` and you will get the best performance for your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check to see if the link starts with a `#`:

http://jsfiddle.net/S9tTE/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mainNav a").bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
        if ($(this).attr('href').indexOf('#') != 0)
            return;

        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('prevented default');
    });
});
```

---

Or give the links you want to scroll a class and only bind to those:

```
$(".mainNav a.scroll-link").bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
```

Or give the links you don't want to scroll a class and don't bind to those:

```
$(".mainNav a:not('.dont-scroll')").bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
```

Comment: this is perfect for me thank you, first one suits me, others ill need to customize WP

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the anchors before applying the event handler:

```
$('.mainNav a')
    .filter(function() {
        return this.getAttribute('href')[0] == '#';
    })
    .on('click.smoothscroll', function() ...
```

This selects only the anchors with the href attribute starting with '#'.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though this code is geared towards internally scrolling your document when the user clicks on local anchor tags on the page. With that in mind, I would recommend using a slightly modified selector to only target anchor tags with hrefs beginning with the id hash `#`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".mainNav a[href^='#']").bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
    ...
  });
});
```